# Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool unable to connect to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to use the [Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data), but it is unable to connect to my database.

In the documentation it is stated that -

> The format of the Azure Cosmos DB connection string is:
>   `AccountEndpoint=<CosmosDB Endpoint>;AccountKey=<CosmosDB Key>;Database=<CosmosDB Database>;`

To that end, I took the 'Primary Connection String' from my Cosmos DB account and appended the database name -

> AccountEndpoint=https://my-cosmos-db.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=**********;Database=Accounts;

However, any connection attempt from the Data Migration Tool is met with an error stating that it is unable to establish a connection (timeout). I am however to `telnet` to the Cosmos DB account on port `443`.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Target Information" tab, change your Connection Mode to Gateway